# How can I get Noise and Photos to recognize my phone?

Tags: music, usb-drive, photo-editing

I am trying to sync my Samsung Galaxy S6 to Noise and Photos, but Noise won't recognize it at all, and Photos gives me the following error.

[image: Photos: Unable to fetch previews from camera: Could not claim the USB device (-53)]

Does anyone know how I can get these programs to recognize my phone as a storage device to sync photos and music?

Thanks!

Comment: Two things to try. 1) After failing to mount, open a terminal and type `dmesg`.  There might be an error message. 2) Try connecting your phone as an MTP device (in the phones usb settings)

Comment: Then following [these](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702) steps.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @elmato better post your solution as answer

Comment: No I didn't. dmesg didn't throw any errors (that I could see), it saw my phone fine. It connects as MTP by default so that wasn't the problem either. Any other ideas?

Comment: OH hang on!! I didn't see elmato's other comment until now. Let me try that.

Comment: Yes, it did work for everything EXCEPT Noise. Noise still doesn't see my phone.

Answer (score 2):

Install `mtpfs` (If not installed), this will *probably* solve the issue.

To install open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install mtpfs
```

Comment: Does not work for me