# MTP device connecting problem in files

Tags: mount, android, mtp

The files from my android device get detected only when there is an internet connection. If I am not connected to internet I get an error message: "Unable to mount folder. The server for this folder could not be located." I can open my files (device will get mounted) once I go online on my system.
Please help to fix this. I want to connect my phone without going online.[image]

Comment: MTP works for me out of the box. What are the specs of the host machine and the Android device?

Comment: Host machine : elementary os freya (intel i5, 4gb ram, Radeon Graphics). Phone: Android L (Asus zenfone 4.5 (Zen UI),). Also noticed that only my phone doesn't get mounted; it works well with other android phones :(

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Source:** [Enable MTP-Support on ElementaryOS](http://michael-peeters.blogspot.de/2013/10/enable-mtp-support-on-elementary-os.html)

*Keep in mind that this is a workaround and that the guide is written 2013.*

Comment: 404 not found error. Does not work

Comment: @SuiciDoga [Sorry for that.. Here have a look!](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Enable+MTP-Support+on+ElementaryOS)

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question here: [How can I get Noise and Photos to recognize my phone?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/how-can-i-get-noise-and-photos-to-recognize-my-phone?noredirect=1#comment2180_1017) maybe it will help you out. I was able to get my Galaxy s6 to work (except for Noise).